# Should I use sorting algorithms like bubble sort, insertion sort or should I use the inbuilt sort() function in c++ to sort arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Should I use sorting algorithms like bubble sort, insertion sort or should I use the inbuilt sort() function in c++ to sort arrays? And if I should use sort() function, why do I need to learn other sorting algorithms? I'm not understanding what is the use of such algorithms if there is an inbuilt sort function, do they have something special?

Comment: 1) Use `std::sort`.  2) If you want to implement the other sorting algorithms, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c).  There is a small discussion on what those algorithms give you, and an implementation of them using modern C++.

Comment: sorting is an area of active research, thats why it makes sense to learn about different sorting algorithms. When your only concern is to get something sorted, `std::sort` most likely fits your needs

Comment: Some people find benefit in learning how things work. Sorting algorithms are relatively simple and easy to teach, so they tend to get taught to lots of training programmers, but it's not necessary to learn them to do most programming jobs. That said, it will be more difficult to get hired in many places since they test algorithms and datastructures knowledge in interviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I use sorting algorithms like bubble sort, insertion sort or should I use the inbuilt sort() function in c++ to sort arrays?

It is your wish. You can use anything. But you need to understand the importance of time and space complexity, your requirement  before using any code.

> And if I should use sort() function, why do I need to learn other sorting algorithms?

The answer to this is tricky. You need to learn stuff because each sorting algorithm is different on implementation, time and space complexities. For instance, bubble sort runs in O(n^2) time while merge sort takes O(n log n) time.
while space taken by bubble sort is O(1) and merge sort takes O(n) space.In terms of code complexity, you could write a bubble sort snippet in 5 minutes while merge sort could take 30 minutes.

> I'm not understanding what is the use of such algorithms if there is an inbuilt sort function, do they have something special?

Yes they do. It is to do with requirements. Today , you might not need a space effecient algorithm. But when such a case arises, you may need to prefer a particular algorithm over the other. In general, you learn these concepts just to understand how the current algorithms have been developed.

Comment: you had quote and non-quote formatting reversed

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::sort`.

Standard libraries are hyper-optimized and `std::sort` will actually utilize different algorithms based on the size of the data.

Of course, as an exercise, it's still worthwhile to go through all the sorting algorithms and understand how they work.

EDIT: this talk by Andrei Alexandrescu is a great exploration into the complexities of implementing a fast sorting algorithm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJJTYQYB1JQ But, beware, it's a pretty advanced one.